# How to access Front-Facing Camera through CameraCaptureTask in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera

I am developing a Selfie Cam App for Windows Phone 8, I don't want to use the PhotoCamera library and Video Brush etc... to manually get the front facing cam.

I want to use the CameraCaptureTask to show the camera. As all know better, that when we launch the CameraCaptureTask, it shows the Primery(Back) camera, but I need that when the Task launch it shows the Front Facing Cam first.

Plz help in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

**`CameraCapture` task don't have option to select front-facing camera.**

you've to write your own code to Launch front-facing camera by default.

**Possibilities:**

`CameraCaptureTask` is WP8 API, and i don't think that Microsoft is going to provide any option in future with `CameraCaptureTask`.

But in WP8.1 (wp Store apps), there are no alternative for `CameraCaptureTask` yet, so in future Microsoft might come out with something similar to `CameraCaptureTask` which might contain option to launch front-facing camera by default.

**Edit:**

**Capture Image/Video with exact orientation:-**

If you're facing issue of image capture orientation while capturing image or recording video, you should have to rotate the `VideoBrush` to 90 degree. So that the recorded video/Image will be captured as you wish.

Check the code for this function.

You need to edit the `XAML` code where you've created the `VideoBrush control`.

```
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasLayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <!--Camera viewfinder >-->
        <Rectangle x:Name="viewfinderRectangle"
                   Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=CanvasLayoutRoot}"
                   Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=CanvasLayoutRoot}"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" Margin="-144 145" >

            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>

        </Rectangle>

    </Canvas>
```

Here main thing to notice is `<Rectangle.RenderTransform>` part and two tags `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5"` and `Margin="-144 145"` of  control.

after setting the UI, assign `VideoCaptureDevice` to rectangle and you're done..!!

Hope that helps..

Comment: Ok. I will use the PhotoCamera library to get image stream in Canvas VideoBrush, but the problem is the Orientation of the image when captured and saved. Do u have any idea how to handle the orientation?
You should try this experiment practically then u will understand better what am I saying. There seems to be a Bug in Camera library, wherein the Camera show the PortraitUp to down and the ProtraitDown to up....
No idea how to handle.... plz.

Comment: I'm aware about the issue that you're saying..! Actually Camera Library in wp8 have a limitation that you should have to use Camera library in "Landscape Page orientation" to make everything work as you wish. If you try to put it in Portrait page orientation then you've to change the orientation of captured image by rotating the ImageStream.

I'll try to provide code in some time...

Comment: OK great! It will be much appreciated, if you provide the exact code. waiting for your response and link of code. plz.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman check the edited answer. I've added the code to fix orientation issue of capturing image or recording video. let me know whether that's working or not..! all the best..